# can I connect a two battery packs that are made up of different cells with different chemistry say for a short period of time?

Tags: batteries

I have an e-scooter.  It's really horrible when it comes to batteries.  The charge runs out in an hour or after the first big hill.  It is powered by 4 sla's 12v but when it comes to ah the story is sketchy.  It's 15ah over 2 hours, but you can drain it in 30 min or just going up a big hill, realistically 9ah.  Interesting fact is that I bought the scooter for $180 with batteries that were completely melted.  As the batteries get worse the frustration gets worse too.  I Also, I think that they should have put 8 sla's in it.  There is plenty of space.  Spring is coming soon.  I want to add at least another 12v sla in parallel.  Today I read that mixing old and new batteries makes them overheat.  I also want to make a battery pack out of Panasonic NCR18650B cells, they are tiny laptop lithium battery cells.  This will sound dumb but can I add a 12volt battery pack made of 18650 connected in parallel.  I've been researching a lot and it seems like my ideas will end with something blowing up or overheating.  What if I add a switch that I only switch on for say 5 min while holding my hand on the lithium battery pack to make sure it's not getting hot.  There are 22 volt lipo battery packs, so my question is can I connect this 22v lipo battery in parallel with a switch that is only on while going up a hill that drains my batteries.  I understand that it's a bad idea.  Maybe this is a million dollar idea for pieca chit Chinese scooters.  Any suggestions?

Comment: More like Chinese hover board exploding battery idea.

Comment: Never put different kinds / different voltages / different ages / different chemistry batteries in parallel. Why make your own pack, why not just buy a good 12V battery pack for this? What is your motivation? (Yes, there are obvious reasons, but what are yours?) Also, please use paragraphs; it makes our job easier.

Comment: Also, AH is the capacity rating in amp hours. So 15AH means the battery can deliver 15 amps (continuously) over the course of one hour (and then be empty). Barring discharge limitations of the battery, this could also mean 30 amps for 30 minutes, 60 A for 15 minutes, 5 A for 3 hours, etc. The way you have described the AH ratings makes absolutely no sense. Going up a hill, the motors will draw significantly more current; hence, the run time will be significantly reduced.

Comment: Batteries, especially SLAs, do not have a linear discharge curve.  They achieve the sticker rating only at a very low current.  For example, a 5Ah battery would achieve that capacity with a 20 hour discharge, but would achieve only 2Ah with a 30-minute discharge.  4Ah means 200mA for 20 hours, or 3.2A for half an hour.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFkqGD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SLAs are a terrible choice to run a scooter, because the current draw is many times higher than what the batteries were designed to support.  That means they get hot, give you very little energy, and fail quickly... as you're discovering.

If you put two batteries in parallel, significant current will flow between them according to the difference in their terminal voltages.  So in general, doing so is a really bad idea unless the cells are first carefully balanced and then permanently connected to each other.  If they're different chemistries though, that would be a silly thing to do.

If you want to have an alternate/booster battery, the best option would be a changeover switch, i.e single pole double throw, which selects which of the batteries are connected to the controller.  That way, the batteries are never connected to each other and can't destroy each other, and you can change over from one to the other when the first dies.

Make sure your switch is rated for a large enough current to support the motor, probably 20A or so; they're sold in auto-electrical stores as battery isolator/changeover switches.  Don't operate the switch with the motor running, and you probably want to turn the controller off too before switching otherwise it may die.

Comment: You do realize the SLA is a lead acid battery... the same type of battery that puts out massive amounts of current to start an automobile... right? The S just means sealed - maintenance free. Also, unless this is a motorized child's toy scooter, I'd imagine the motors are drawing substantially more current than 20A (and even then, on a hill I wouldn't doubt it). Also, if a switch has truly isolated connections (and few SPDT do), there will be a momentary break in power while switching, but it's more likely that there will be a momentary short between the batteries. This is horrible advice.

Comment: The term SLA is synonymous in most markets with a Gel Cell, which is designed for 0.05C (20 hour) discharge rate at the rated capacity.  An SLA is far, far less capable in terms of discharge current than a liquid-electrolyte, vehicle-starter battery, the tradeoff being that they can operate in any orientation without the electrolyte pouring out.  Also, good luck finding a changeover switch that is make-before-break.  99.9% of them are break-before-make and you have to pay significant more for make-before-break.  Take your horrible advice somewhere else.

Comment: Your typical cheap scooter is 200W max, if only because that's the legal limit for unregistered vehicles in places like Australia.  200W from 12V is under 17A and if the 4 batteries are used to form a 48V pack (pretty likely!) then we're talking under 5A.  It takes a pretty insane scooter (about 1kW) to need a switch rated for more than 20A, and note that the switch rating is the current it is capable of safely interrupting into a resistive load.  A mechanical switch will take significantly more as long as you don't try to open it under load and burn the contacts.

Comment: and google up "battery isolator".  You can buy off-the-shelf switches designed to do exactly this, e.g. for 4WD camping etc.  They're good for hundreds of amps and do not short the batteries together.

Comment: Here's an SLA datasheet showing the capacity-vs-load table.  Going to 2C (half hour) discharge means you get only about 40% of the rated capacity: http://www.batteryweb.com/manuals/techman.pdf

Comment: It's a gio pb 710 scooter.  500W motor.  48v 17A controller.  I ride it to the beer store and back to get beer. Beer store is 2.2km away.  Me and the scooter weigh around 250lb.  There is a hugh hill on the way.

Comment: This whole madness is powered by 4 sla's that likely pump out about 9ah or something.  48vx9ah=432wh

Comment: I do not think they are going to last long.  For a fat boy like me riding it up hill with 2 x 24 of beer.  I would say that you need 8 sla or a different kind of batteries.  Is it too late to add more sla's?  I bought these 4 in august so it has been 4 month.

Comment: It is hard to take a truly engineering approach to this.  I order 2 more sla's put them in the trunk.  connect it in parallel, what will happend.  the speed up the hill is 4km an hour if it drops further I am going to have to walk.

Comment: From dumb kid RC car perspective, can't I just add 2 more batteries of the same kind.  i never tried this in an rc car, but i don't think it would blow.

Comment: this spring I want to spend $150-200 to improve the situation.  I guess I could get a second battery pack that would add another 32lb to the total weight.  I could buy a switch at Canadian tire that disconnects one and connects the other.

Comment: Budget is important in this.  can I just spend $80 and add 2 more batteries.  The load is just too much for these, it seems.  My budget on this isn't exactly engineer worthy.  I can just ride it on the old batteries the hill is only one way the other way it's down hill.  The scooters total range was around 13km when I bought the batteries.  They might still get 9-10 km and this trip is only 5km.

Comment: @WilliamBrodie-Tyrrell Your assumptions about the setup were your downfall. Your information is only true in certain circumstances. This scooter runs at 48 V. Those 4 batteries are in series, not parallel. http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/alinawong/product-detailqoAJfNrugpWO/China-Electric-Scooter-Bicycle-PB710-.html

Comment: If you want to add more batteries to get a higher power, the best approach is to upgrade all of the batteries to a larger size.  Larger batteries will handle the larger current better, because it's lower current density within the electrolyte.

Comment: Kurt: the cells being in series does not change my answer or its correctness, and nowhere do I state that the batteries must be in parallel.  A 20A changeover switch will work fine as a changeover to a secondary battery since the max load is 17A.  It's not much more convenient than plugging/unplugging batteries though.